# How can I extract the date part from this text in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

the text is :

`<div class="fi-mu-list today" data-matchesdate="20180619">`

I want to extract `20180619` from this.

I tried :
1)

`mat  = soup.select("div.fi-mu-list today > span.fi-mu-list__head__date")
print(mat["data-matchesdate"])`

output : `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

2)
also tried `print(mat)`

output : `[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup.find`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = '<div class="fi-mu-list today" data-matchesdate="20180619">'
result = soup(s, 'html.parser').find('div')['data-matchesdate']
```

Output:

```
'20180619'
```